# Calling a locally hosted web service

Tags: c#, web-services, localhost

I have a web service on a virtual development machine. This - as you would expect -  works fine and all of my web methods are called and return as expected. Now I wish to call this web service from my base machine but I'm not sure of how to go about doing this.

What is the correct procedure to carry out the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to deploy the web services on IIS, you can do it in multiple ways one by using publishing utility

Comment: @I have the site deployed onto IIS, I'm thinking that I haven't got it configured correctly though. Can you explain further how I would go about 'publishing utility'?

Comment: kindly find the following link http://www.csharptutorial.in/2012/01/cnet-how-to-publish-web-service-in-iis.html